# Динамическое создание реплики сайта

Tags: php

Есть нестандартная задача. Звучит она приблизительно так. Есть какой-то сайт, site.ru, который является интернет-магазином. Необходимо "скопировать" сайт, но изменить только шапку (логотип поменять) и калькулятор при формировании цены за доставку.

По сути, нужно как-то парсить HTML код этого сайта. Первое, что пришло в голову, это представить HTML как XML. И работать как с XML объектом. Но уже вижу много проблем (запрещенные символы), по которым эта идея отпадает.

Может быть кто-то уже сталкивался с этим? Что посоветуете? Сайт копируется полностью. Даже URI все сохраняются.

Получить доступ к БД не вариант. Также не вариант постоянно парсить саму БД того сайта: каталог меняется.

Вообщем, жду советов, спасибо...

Comment: То есть, Вы хотели сказать 'своровать'?

Comment: Это самая обычная задача. Называется "сграбить чужие данные и выдать за свои".

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать одну такую вещь. Взять фрейм, поставить на вашем сайте с размером в полную ширину и в полную высоту. То есть, это будет выглядеть как будто бы сайт находится на этом домене. А фрейм можно изменять через js (jQuery). То есть можно обращаться к любому DOM элементу и сделать с ним, что хотите.

Answer (score 0):

ajax?

Как вариант, возможно обратить к интересующей вас странице посредством аякс, отсечь "голову" и добавить в свой файл...